# iOS and Android push notifications with Meteor

Tags: android, ios, meteor

I installed the package "raix:push" on my meteor app. I would expect it to ask the user of the app if they want to receive push notifications, but it doesn't. Is there some sort of code that I need to add to my client/server files to make it ask them if they want to receive push notifications? And then will it send the data to Apple and Google? I have set up my config file with all of the necessary keys.

Comment: have you looked at the basic example here: https://github.com/raix/push/blob/master/docs/BASIC.md

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a function to store this information on the user.profile document than pass it to the query of the push notification. Something like that:

```js
        function setUser(userId)
        {
          Meteor.users.update({_id: userId},{$set: {'profile.push_notifications': true}});
          return 1;
        }


var arrayUsersIds = Meteor.users.find({"profile.push_notifications": true});

sendPush(arrayUsersIds);


function sendPushs(arrayUsersIds)

Push.send({
        from: 'push',
        title: 'Hello',
        text: 'world',
        badge: 1, //optional, use it to set badge count of the receiver when the app is in background.
        query: {
            // Ex. send to a specific user if using accounts:
             userId: {$in : arrayUsersIds} 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To receive push notifications in the app using "raix:push", you also need to install the Cordova npm plugin phonegap-plugin-push, if using version 3(three) of "raix:push". Do this by opening a terminal window and cd in to your meteor project. Then enter the command below to install phonegap-plugin-push. Meteor requires exact version of the Cordova plugin.

```
meteor add cordova:phonegap-plugin-push@1.5.2
```